# Firebase Admin SDK - Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Recently the FB Admin SDK was [introduced](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/bringing-firebase-to-your-server.html) for Python as well, and here is a repo with some [samples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-python).

It's nice I can authenticate using credentials, and finally I have a `firebase_admin` authenticated which can create Custom Tokens too. But how can it help to do requests for the REST API e.g? Can I retrieve my authentication token and set it as Authorization header maybe to do API requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to get an OAuth token by calling the `get_access_token()` method on your credential, and then pass it to the REST API as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth#section-using-the-access-token).

However, in the v1.0.0 of the Python Admin SDK, the returned credential does not contain the Firebase scopes. Therefore the OAuth token obtained from the credential will not readily work with the REST API. This is a bug, and it will be addressed in a future release. In the meantime you can use the following trick:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials

scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
]

cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceKey.json')
token = cred.get_credential().create_scoped(scopes).get_access_token().access_token
# Pass token to REST API
```

In a future release, once the bug has been fixed, you will be to do the following:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceKey.json')
token = cred.get_access_token().access_token
# Pass token to REST API
```